# setAuthenticationChallengeBlock is undefined (not found) - AFNetworking

Tags: authentication, ios5, afnetworking, afhttpclient

I am trying to set the basic authentication using the AFNetworking with 
'setAuthenticationChallengeBlock' But compiler says its not found.

Setting the username and password with 'setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername' not working either

Please Help!!

Comment: Did you try `#import "AFURLConnectionOperation.h"`?

Comment: Certainly, even I have searched for this in AFNetworking Dir.

Comment: Can you post the method in which you're getting that error?